# Simple gridview as an cardview

Tags: android, material-design, android-gridview, android-cardview

`CardView` has beautiful structure and I like it. But for `GridView` as an `CardView` I must be using a nine patch background to have a structure like I have with the `CardView`.

Can I simply use `CardView` structure as an `GridView`? In `CardView` after rotate screen we have full width but I want to separator like with `GridView`.

How to create

1. Create `CardView` as an `GridView` structure;
2. Create `GridView` like with `CardView`.

Can I do one of those items?

Comment: do you want your whole gridview to be in a cardview? (if so, just put your gridview in a cardview) or your gridview to contain cardviews? (if so, just wrap your cells layout into cardviews)

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/766590/A-Custom-Grid-List-Adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my logic:

**card_item.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**gridview_item.xml**:

```
<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

[image: My logic]

Comment: i think this is good solution. please let me to test it. thanks